# ycor() 'if' condition in turtle graphics game not being met for some odd reason

Tags: python-3.x

I am quite new to python (using python 3.10 interpreter) and I am creating a turtle traffic game where if the turtle object (player) gets to a certain y coordinate (towards the top of the screen) it triggers a method for the object. I've been stuck on figuring out why my condition is not being met (please see some screenshots below). I want the code to trigger the print statement ("reached") when the ycor() of the turtle object is > 100. I can't seem to pinpoint where I'm going wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[Screenshot of my code and the game screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGUNT.png)

Comment: [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also don't upload screenshot but code . Print  what  play.ycor() value is, this could help you determine why condition isn't met

Answer (score 0):

The only problem with your `if` statement is where it is located. Currently it's at top level, among a bunch of other code that you expect to only run once. Like that other code, the test is being run once, right at the start of the program. Since (presumably) the turtle starts below the finish line, you're not ever going to see it print the message.

You can fix the problem by moving the `if` statement into the code that moves the turtle, probably part of the `Player` class. That code runs each time the turtle moves, so it will repeat the test each time too.

Comment: hey thanks man :)

I was banging my head against the desk on this one.
Its weird because i have a similar code for the snake game i developed and it seems to work ok. 
I have learnt something new which is the main thing !